# Invalid arguments in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, invalid-argument

I am having trouble getting this code to compile. I am new to MVC/Stackoverflow/programming and trying to follow a tutorial. Also, I tried looking some things up and saw some options with Nullable values, but wasn't having much luck.

```
public class ReviewsController : Controller
{
    OdeToFoodDB _db = new OdeToFoodDB();
    //
    // GET: /Reviews/

    //default action
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Reviews.FindTheLatest(3);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the definition for the FindTheLatest

```
public static IEnumerable<RestaurantReview> FindTheLatest(this IList<RestaurantReview>        
reviews, int numberOfReviews)
    {
        return reviews.OrderByDescending(r => r.Created)
                      .Take(numberOfReviews);
   }
```

Here is also the definition to the OdeToFood if that is needed.

```
namespace OdeToFood.Models
{
public class OdeToFoodDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RestaurantReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
}
```

I am getting an error saying:
'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'FindTheLatest' and the best extension method overload 'OdeToFood.Queries.RestaurantReviewQueries.FindTheLatest(System.Collections.Generic.IList, int)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your extension method to use `IEnumerable<T>`, a common base type shared by both `DbSet<T>` and `List<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<RestaurantReview> FindTheLatest(
           this IEnumerable<RestaurantReview> reviews, int numberOfReviews)
```

Comment: thanks! Wish they had mentioned to change that but it's all good now